# Parsing SQL AM/PM for comparison

Tags: mysql, date-parsing

Is it possible to parse AM & PM times in SQL and use them for comparison?

For example, a statement like the following:

`STR_TO_DATE(pack_time_min) <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

With data like so: `1:30pm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse 12-hour times this way:

```
STR_TO_DATE('1:30pm', '%l:%i%p')
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| str_to_date('1:30pm', '%l:%i%p') |
+----------------------------------+
| 13:30:00                         |
+----------------------------------+
```

That's a TIME value, not a DATETIME. The `NOW()` function will return a DATETIME, so you should use `CURRENT_TIME()` instead.

```
mysql> select current_time() + interval 1 hour;
+----------------------------------+
| current_time() + interval 1 hour |
+----------------------------------+
| 02:57:13                         |
+----------------------------------+
```

Then you can compare a TIME to a TIME.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('1:30pm', '%l:%i%p') <= current_time() + interval 1 hour;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('1:30pm', '%l:%i%p') <= current_time() + interval 1 hour |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```